# Search and replace on command line

Tags: perl

Is there a tighter (less characters) way to use perl on the command line to search and replace text from STDIN than I've got here? The code below works.

```
echo hi | perl -e '$a = <STDIN>; $a =~ s/i/o/g; print $a;'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `-p` option (see `perl --help`):

> assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed

So the script becomes:

```
echo hi | perl -pe 's/i/o/g'
```

which is really compiled to:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pe 's/i/o/g'
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/i/o/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```